# MVC evento Change de un TexBox funciona sólo la primera vez

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el inconveniente que el evento `Change` me lo toma una única vez al realizar un `POST` con `AJAX`. Si adentro del evento ingreso únicamente un `alert`, sí me lo ejecuta x veces.

¿Estará mal algo del post?

Este es mi código:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('input[name=FechaDesde]').change(function () {
            alert("pasa");
            var fechaDato = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("BuscarPendientesFecha", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { fecha: fechaDato.toString() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#grillaClientes').html('');
                    $('#grillaClientes').append(data);
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
    <p class="form-control-static">Fecha Desde:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
    <div class='input-group date'>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                    <input type='text' id="fecha" name="FechaDesde" value="@ViewBag.Fecha" class="form-control calendario col-sm-4" readonly="readonly" onkeydown="return ValidateFecha(event);" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="grillaClientes">
</div>
```

Comment: Usted recibe algun tipo de error? Probe su codigo, con otra URL obviamente y funciona bien.

Comment: El problema es que el evento lo añades a inputs del DOM que luego, al hacer el POST, son eliminados y nuevos inputs son creados. Como no vuelves a ejecutar el script para añadir a los nuevos inputs el evento, estos inputs no tiene evento. La propuesta de Jose Luis es una buena solucion ya que utiliza lo que se llama "event delegation", googlealo!

Answer (score 1):

Esto hará que el evento change se aplique a aquellos elementos dentro del body de tipo input que tengan el nombre "FechaDesde". Ahora, puedes cambiar body por un elemento tal como un div que contenga el input al que deseas agregarle el evento.

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[name=FechaDesde]',function () {
        alert("pasa");
        var fechaDato = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("BuscarPendientesFecha", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { fecha: fechaDato.toString() },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#grillaClientes').html('');
                $('#grillaClientes').append(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Te envia la petición? Si la envia revisa que la response es un 200(OK). Tiene toda la pinta de que no se esta ejecutando el success de ajax.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Quizás convendría mostrar con código cómo ver la respuesta cuando no termina en 2xx.

Answer (score 0):

He probado cambiando la URL y el código funciona correctamente. Lo único que veo es que falta un `</div>` al final del HTML, pero supongo que te lo dejaste al copiarlo.

Te sugiero, que después de la función success, agregues lo siguiente:

```
,fail: function(error) {
   console.log(error)
}
```

Así puedes comprobar si la petición falla y el mensaje de error. De otra manera, sólo se me ocurre pensar en una librería externa que estés usando, como datepicker, esté capturando el evento.

Comment: por favor traduce tu respuesta a español.